"Package 'graphql' support only TS versions that are >=4.1.0"
I'm builing a React-Typescript project, using Vite and Vitest as the unit test runner. I'm trying to run tsc -b && vite build but I got this error in the terminal
> sdt-global-ui@0.0.0 build
> tsc -b && vite build

node_modules/graphql/NotSupportedTSVersion.d.ts:1:63 - error TS1003: Identifier expected.

1 "Package 'graphql' support only TS versions that are >=4.1.0".
                                                                


Found 1 error.

I've found the package 'graphql' is used in the following packages, here's the output of npm ls graphql
└─┬ @vitest/browser@2.1.2
  └─┬ msw@2.4.9
    └── graphql@16.9.0

I need the "@vitest/broswer" dependency, how can I solve this.
PS. I'm already using the Typescript version "^5.5.3"
